# Redraw all container if are created with method [DART]

Tags: flutter, dart

I write my first app, i created three container with method, but if the method setState() in a container it's call the setState do not redraw other containers.

```
 Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  //ELEMENT A
                  elementGS(size, value_A.text, Colors.cyan[600], GSConst.sizeA, 2),
                  //ELEMENT B
                  elementGS(size, value_B.text, Colors.blue, GSConst.sizeB, 1),
                ],
              ),
              //ELEMENT C
              elementGS(size, value_AB.text, Colors.red, 1, 3),
            ],
          ),
```

Method for draw a container

```
Container elementGS(
      Size size, String textHint, Color color, double ratioWidth, int flagGS) {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: GSConst.kDefaultPadding),
      height: size.height * GSConst.kHeightElementRatio,
      width: sizeInternalBody.width * ratioWidth,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: color,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30)),
      ),
      child: TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: textHint,
          hintStyle: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontFamily: 'ChristopherDone',
            fontSize: 30,
          ),
          enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
          focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
          alignLabelWithHint: true,
        ),
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
          fontFamily: 'ChristopherDone',
          fontSize: 30,
        ),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        autocorrect: false,
        showCursor: true,
        onChanged: (String value) {
          setState(() {
            if (value.isNotEmpty) {
              Map<String, TextEditingController> contr = {
                "A": value_A,
                "B": value_B,
                "AB": value_AB,
              };
              switch (flagGS) {
                case 1:
//In calculateGS calculate the golden ratio and set value in the textcontroller.
                  contr = calculateGS(contr, b: double.parse(value));
                  break;
                case 2:
                  contr = calculateGS(contr, a: double.parse(value));
                  break;
                case 3:
                  contr = calculateGS(contr, ab: double.parse(value));
                  break;
              }
            }
          });
        },
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
      ),
    );
```

if I call setState in "element C" I also want redraw "element A" and "element B".
It's possible?

Here you will find all the code
[GITHUB GOLDEN RATIO](https://github.com/EliaTolin/GoldenSection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if I call setState in "element C" I also want redraw "element A" and "element B". It's possible?

Sure! That what youre doing is just not really that what you are expecting because every widget you create, has just its own state which gets updated.
If you want to observe states in other widgets too, you should read (or watch, or learn) a little bit about the BLoC Pattern(Link: https://bloclibrary.dev/#/ ), or in your case, bc its not very big, Provider (https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple ) both are recommended from the flutter team, so choose one what fits your knowlegde and your requirements.